# wrong output format from cron

Tags: php, cron, txt

```
#cron_task
0 0 * * * php /var/www/mysite/for_test_cron.php >> /var/www/mysite/log.txt 2>> /var/www/mysite/error_log.txt
```

The log.txt file is correct

The error_log.txt file is saved in this format:

```
'error_log.txt'$'\r'
```

Output file is incorrect and unreadable.
How to fix it?

Comment: What kind of "format" are you talking about? And how is this related to PHP, if the error log is written by cron?

Comment: You need to show your php code and explain what output you are expecting.